# Spring Boot HTTPServletRequest not properly available through test

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I tried to search the answer here, but couldn't find it. So here it goes: I am using Spring Boot. I am parsing Query String dynamically using

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/processors")
public class ProcessorsController {

    protected static transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessorsController.class);

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    private Options options = new Options();

    @Autowired
    ProcessorRepository processorRepository;

    //Inside a method, I am populating the Options<String, String> map using
    //request.getParameterMap() 

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}/run", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String run(@RequestBody String input, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        Validate.notEmpty(input, "The request body must contain an not empty text");
        return runProcessor(input, name);
    }

    private String runProcessor(String input, String name) {
        Validate.notEmpty(name, "The processor name cannot be empty");
        Processor processor = processorRepository.getProcessorCalled(name);
        addOptions();
        return processor.run(input, options);
    }

    private void addOptions() {
        request.getParameterMap().forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (!k.equals("text")) {
                if (v[0] != null && !v[0].isEmpty()) {
                    options.put(k, v[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine in manual testing, but I am trying to write a unit test. Following is the example:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {HAL.class, ProcessorsController.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class ProcessorsControllerAbstractTest {

    MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    ProcessorRepository processorRepository;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    ProcessorsController processorsController;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        processorsController.processorRepository = processorRepository;
        processorsController.request = request;
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(processorsController).build();
    }
}
```

and 
within the actual test class

```
public class ProcessorsControllerTest extends ProcessorsControllerAbstractTest {
    //other test cases
    @Test
    public void testAddOptions() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/processors/default/run").param("size", "500").content(input).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
        Assert.assertEquals("500", options.get("size"));
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the request object values (e.g. params like `size`) at `request.getParameterMap()`. Is there any way I can access it? If not, what would be another way to test it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you mind adding the code for `ProcessorsController`? At least the annotations and first line of the class definition?

Comment: @JonathanThoms I just edited the code. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: I would guess it's due to the autowiring of the request. MockMvc knows nothing about it so it won't be setting the parameters on it. Try getting rid of the field and make it an argument of the `ProcessorsController.run` method instead.

Comment: You shouldn't be auto wiring the `HttpServletRequest` that is a very bad idea. Just add it as a method argument and pass it to the methods needed. Also your controller is flawed as you should NEVER store state inside an instance variable. (What would happen if 2 request come in and modify the single `Options` instance?). Also why do you do the manual parsing? Why not simply let Spring MVC handle this... You should be working with the framework and not around it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be auto wiring the `HttpServletRequest` that is a very bad idea.

Instead add a `@RequestParam Map<String,String> params` to your method signature, this will automatically contain all parameters. As explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) in the reference guide.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}/run", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
String run(@RequestBody String input, @PathVariable("name") String name, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    Validate.notEmpty(input, "The request body must contain an not empty text");
    return runProcessor(input, name, params);
}
```

Now your controller is also flawed by storing the `Options` as an instance variable. the controller is a singleton now imagine what happens when 10 request all at the same time start modifying this instance. Change your `runProcessor` and `addOptions` method for this.

```
private String runProcessor(String input, String name, Map<String, String> params) {
    Validate.notEmpty(name, "The processor name cannot be empty");
    Processor processor = processorRepository.getProcessorCalled(name);
    Options options = new Options();
    addOptions(options, params);
    return processor.run(input, options);
}

private void addOptions(Options options, Map<String, String> params) {
    params.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (!k.equals("text")) {
            if (v != null && !v.isEmpty()) {
                options.put(k, v);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You might want to add the `addOptions` to the `Options` class instead (or add it to the constructor for instance so that you can construct an `Options` instance with a `Map<String, String>`.